# SQL Server 2008 Select Count and Parameter Value in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, parameters

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and I'm trying to run a `SELECT COUNT` first. Once checking if the count is equals to 0, I need to replace a specific parameter's value. If the count is one, I need to get the values from the table. Currently here's my script:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[csp_LoginAuthentication]
    @employeeid VARCHAR (20),
    @password VARCHAR (20),
    @accountstatus INT OUT,
    @logincount INT OUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;     

    DECLARE @rowCnt INT    

    SELECT @rowCnt = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                      FROM strato_blueapplesmis.dbo.app_login
                      WHERE 1 = 1
                        AND employee_id = @employeeid
                        AND password = @password)

    IF @rowCnt = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @accountstatus = 2
        SET @logincount = 0
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT
            @accountstatus = account_status,
            @logincount = logincount
        FROM 
            strato_blueapplesmis.dbo.app_login
        WHERE 
            1 = 1
            AND employee_id = @employeeid
            AND password = @password
        END
    END         
END
```

And I'm getting the following error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure csp_LoginAuthentication, Line 41
>   Incorrect syntax near 'END'.

Please help, I really do appreciate everyone's suggestions and feedback, I'm not quite sure if I'm on the right track and I feel I'm kinda lost.

Comment: Remove the last `END`, for you have one too many.

Comment: You should NOT be storing passwords in plain text. Passwords should hashed and salted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too many ends.  Remove one of them.  Specifically this:

```
 ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT
                @accountstatus = account_status,
                @logincount = logincount
            FROM strato_blueapplesmis.dbo.app_login
            WHERE 1 = 1
                AND employee_id = @employeeid
                AND password = @password
        END
    END
```

You have a BEGIN and END in the else, you dont need the extra END.  Your entire code comes out to this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[csp_LoginAuthentication]
    @employeeid VARCHAR (20),
    @password VARCHAR (20),
    @accountstatus INT OUT,
    @logincount INT OUT
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;     
    DECLARE @rowCnt INT    
    SELECT @rowCnt = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                        FROM strato_blueapplesmis.dbo.app_login
                        WHERE 1 = 1
                            AND employee_id = @employeeid
                            AND password = @password)
    IF @rowCnt = 0
        BEGIN
            SET @accountstatus = 2
            SET @logincount = 0
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT
                @accountstatus = account_status,
                @logincount = logincount
            FROM strato_blueapplesmis.dbo.app_login
            WHERE 1 = 1
                AND employee_id = @employeeid
                AND password = @password
        END      
END
```

Also what is the point of `WHERE 1 = 1` ?